# How to concatenate string values in two lists without creating duplicates?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists that I am trying to join. They two become one. A partial match between the values is used to merge the values.

```
list1 = ["15:09.123", "15:09.234", "15:09.522", "15:09.621", "15:10.123", "15:11.123", "15:12.123", "15:12.987"]
list2 = ["15:09", "15:09", "15:10", "15:14"]
final = []
for each in list2:
    for each1 in list1:
        if each in each1:
            eachtemp = each1.split(".")[1]
            final.append(each+"."+eachtemp)
            list1.remove(each1)
print(final)
```

This produces an output

```
['15:09.123', '15:09.522', '15:09.234', '15:10.123']
```

But ideal output I want is

```
['15:09.123', '15:09.234', '15:10.123', '15:14.000']
```

It should not contain `"15:09.522", "15:09.621"` even though they have partially matching elements in the list1. The final list should contain all elements in `list2` with 3 more digits acquired from list1 and `final` list should be the same length as `list2`.

Comment: What you describe doesn't sound like "joining" at all, and I'm still struggling to understand the logic. What exactly do you mean about digits being "acquired from" `list1`? Why is the expected output `['15:09.123', '15:09.234', '15:10.123', '15:11.123']`, and not, say, `['15:09.123', '15:09.123', '15:10.123', '15:11.123']`? Why are there nested loops in the code? Try to explain your intended logic, in step-by-step detail, in plain English.

Comment: Maybe you should add a `break` on the `if` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might suggest using an iterator over `list1` and consuming elements from it as you iterate over `list2` (renaming these `ms_list` and `s_list` to make it easier to keep track of which is which):

```
>>> ms_list = ["15:09.123", "15:09.234", "15:09.522", "15:09.621", "15:10.123", "15:11.123", "15:12.123", "15:12.987"]
>>> s_list = ["15:09", "15:09", "15:10", "15:14"]
>>> final = []
>>> ms_iter = iter(ms_list)
>>> for s in s_list:
...     default = f"{s}.000"
...     ms = next(ms_iter, default)
...     while not ms.startswith(s) and ms < s:
...         ms = next(ms_iter, default)
...     final.append(ms if ms.startswith(s) else default)
...
>>> final
['15:09.123', '15:09.234', '15:10.123', '15:14.000']
```

Comment: I am getting `StopIteration` error in `while` loop's `next(ms_iter)` :(

Comment: That's because you don't have a match for the next item.  In the example you gave this isn't a problem, but obviously if you have other types of data then a different approach might be needed.

Comment: thank you. I do have missing items and I have updated the question. Please take a look. P.S. amazing name! big of LOTR